# Package list changed after installing a new package on Anaconda Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I was using an anaconda environment on Ubuntu that had tensoflow, scipy, jupyter, pandas, numpy and many other packages installed. Then I decided to install opencv on this same environment and after doing that, all of the previous packages were gone except for numpy.

I used `conda install opencv` for installing opencv and after running `conda list`, I realized I have lost the packages I mentioned above.

I don't understand how installing a new package deletes others, at least without asking for my permission first. And I really hope there is a way to retain the installed packages because I don't want to reinstall tensorflow again. Thank you.

Additionally, using the revisions feature in anaconda didn't show the previous package list that contained tensorflow, etc.

Edit: I tried something new today. Without being in any environment I typed `conda list` and the output actually contained all the packages I previously installed (I can show you the output if it's really necessary). However when I activate the environment I work on I don't find these packages there, although they were there before installing opencv.

Can you tell me how to make these packages accessible in the working environment again?

Comment: Without seeing the commands you typed and the output, it's impossible to diagnose this.

Comment: I did show the commands I typed? They are highlighted in "code blocks". I will list them for you again anyway.
`conda install opencv` Which it successfully installed. Then I typed:
`conda list` and didn't find my previous installations. I can try other commands if it would help